# RxAndroidBle stopped when discovering another BLE device

Tags: android, rxandroidble

I'm using RxAndroidBle to discovery surrounded devices' service and some characteristics. I met a problem that establishConnection with another device dosn't work after the connection with first device is unsubsribed. When it comes to another device, the state is always "Connection State: RxBleConnectionState{DISCONNECTED}".

Here is the codes, will anyone can help me to have a check!

```
private Subscription createDeviceConnectionSubscription(final RxBleDevice 
rxBleDevice){
    bInternalStatus = DISCOVERRING;
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "start to discover the services on: " + rxBleDevice.getMacAddress().toString());

    Subscription subscription = rxBleDevice.establishConnection(false)
            .timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.from(mWorker.getLooper()))
            .flatMap(new Func1<RxBleConnection, Observable<gattConnectionResults>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<gattConnectionResults> call(RxBleConnection rxBleConnection) {
                    return Observable.zip(
                            rxBleConnection.discoverServices(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS),               
               rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("UUID1")),                                
               rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("UUID2")),
                            new Func3<RxBleDeviceServices, byte[], byte[], gattConnectionResults>() {
                                @Override
                                public gattConnectionResults call(RxBleDeviceServices rxBleDeviceServices, byte[] bytes, byte[] bytes2) {
                                    //......
                                    return results;
                                }
                            }
                    );
                }
            })
            .subscribe(subscriber);

    rxBleDevice.observeConnectionStateChanges()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<RxBleConnection.RxBleConnectionState>() {
                @Override
                public void call(RxBleConnection.RxBleConnectionState rxBleConnectionState) {
                    Log.d("Gatt Connection State", ""+rxBleConnectionState);
                }
            });
 return subscription;
}

Subscriber<gattConnectionResults> subscriber = new 
Subscriber<gattConnectionResults>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "RXXX on completed called!!!");
        if(mDeviceConnectionSubscription!=null){
            handleConnectionOver();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "RXXX Connection error!!! " + e);
        if(mDeviceConnectionSubscription!=null){
            handleConnectionOver();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(gattConnectionResults results) {

        }
    }
};

private void handleConnectionOver(){
    bInternalStatus = STOPPED;
    if(mDeviceConnectionSubscription!=null && !mDeviceConnectionSubscription.isUnsubscribed()){
        mDeviceConnectionSubscription.unsubscribe();
        mDeviceConnectionSubscription = null;
    }
}
```

Thanks for @s-noopy, after move unsubcribe to the end of onNext(), the logs by RxBle are:

```
05-15 D/RxBle#Radio:   QUEUED RxBleRadioOperationConnect(192750313)
05-15 D/RxBle#Radio:  STARTED RxBleRadioOperationConnect(192750313)
05-15 V/RxBle#BleConnectionCompat: Connecting without reflection
05-15 D/RxBle#BluetoothGatt: onConnectionStateChange newState=2 status=0
05-15 D/RxBle#Radio: FINISHED RxBleRadioOperationConnect(192750313)
05-15 D/RxBle#Radio:   QUEUED RxBleRadioOperationServicesDiscover(178598822)
05-15 D/RxBle#Radio:  STARTED RxBleRadioOperationServicesDiscover(178598822)
05-15 D/RxBle#BluetoothGatt: onServicesDiscovered status=0
05-15 D/RxBle#Radio:   QUEUED RxBleRadioOperationCharacteristicRead(241700341)
05-15 D/RxBle#Radio:   QUEUED RxBleRadioOperationCharacteristicRead(24572440)
05-15 D/RxBle#Radio: FINISHED RxBleRadioOperationServicesDiscover(178598822)
05-15 D/RxBle#Radio:  STARTED RxBleRadioOperationCharacteristicRead(241700341)
05-15 D/RxBle#BluetoothGatt: onCharacteristicRead characteristic=00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb status=0
05-15 D/RxBle#Radio: FINISHED RxBleRadioOperationCharacteristicRead(241700341)
05-15 D/RxBle#Radio:  STARTED RxBleRadioOperationCharacteristicRead(24572440)
05-15 D/RxBle#BluetoothGatt: onCharacteristicRead characteristic=00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb status=0
05-15 D/RxBle#Radio:   QUEUED RxBleRadioOperationDisconnect(204169407)
05-15 D/RxBle#Radio: FINISHED RxBleRadioOperationCharacteristicRead(24572440)
05-15 D/RxBle#Radio:  STARTED RxBleRadioOperationDisconnect(204169407)
05-15 D/RxBle#BluetoothGatt: onConnectionStateChange newState=0 status=0
05-15 D/RxBle#Radio: FINISHED RxBleRadioOperationDisconnect(204169407)
```

Comment: Are you sure that you start the second connection? Could you add logs (with `RxBleLog.setLogLevel(RxBleLog.VERBOSE)` enabled?

Comment: Thanks! I used RxBleLog, and found the unsubscription never done by call unsubscribe() in subscriber's onCompleted and onError. I moved the unsubscribe() to the end of onNext(), the unsubscription done and disconnected! but it still dosn't restart the connection with a 2nd device
Please see my logs in the original post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a new `Subscriber` for each `Subscription`. `Subscriber` is stateful and once it will get `onCompleted` or `onError` it will not subscribe again to any other `Observable`.

Alternatively you should use `Observer` instead of `Subscriber`. `Observer` is stateless.

Comment: Thanks very much! I modified the subscribe() with new Subscriber(), now it works great!